# Google bar chart not allowing me to label two bars?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Take the following chart. Everything is as I want except the 2nd label, 'Two', is being ignored, and the first label is being centered beneath both bars. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=200x200&chd=t:10|80&chco=000000,333666&chxt=x,y&chl=One|Two
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've fixed it for you. Here's the code:

```
https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=200x200&chd=t:10,80&chco=000000|333666&chxt=x,y&chl=One|Two
```

And here's the chart:

[image]

The problem was you used a pipe to delimit your chart data. That is you had:

```
chd=t:10|80
```

When you should have used a comma:

```
chd=t:10,80
```

You'll also need to update the delimiting on your color codes to use a pipe instead of a comma

```
chco=000000|333666
```